# How to play a background audio across multiple HTML pages.?

Tags: html, flash, audio

Is there a solution to have the background audio/music play across multiple page on a website, WITHOUT restarting on every page load.

The website currently uses a frameset, but I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without making the whole site AJAX I think frames are the only way.

Here's a tutorial for making an ajax site if you need it.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

It will give you separate addresses for each page.. sorta.

Comment: This is correct.  Otherwise, the browser nukes all of the content and unloads it from memory when you change pages.

Comment: The website is about 7 pages, really simple.  Would making the whole site AJAX allow each section to be crawled by Google.?  That's the main reason I'm looking at a alternative, I think Google doesn't like the frames...

Comment: Would I be able to have 7 distinct URLs.?

Comment: It's going to be kind of a pain, but I think net tuts has a tutorial - I'll find it and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only other alternative is to use site-wide AJAX. Each link would dynamically change the page content without navigating away.

Implementing this is time-consuming. Each dynamically loaded page must be stripped of headers and each link must contain a Javascript event that calls an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Pop a child window minimized with the audio and control with parent HTML pages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).