# Add a background music in website and music should not start from beginning if i goto other page

Tags: html, background-music

I want to add a background music to my website, but i want that music to play continuously across all pages.
For e.g: i have music which is approx 10min, i am on Home page for 2 minutes music starts from 1 second, when i goto other page the music should start from 2 minutes 1 second.

i've searched across Google & StackOverflow but unfortunately didn't found any answer as per my requirement. :(

i just wanted to know that is it possible to do??? If yes then what kind of mechanism is used for that???

Comment: Why? Why would you want to have autoplaying music? Are you a band? Is your website a music playing website?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr its a entertainment website and some soft music playing in background and i don't want user listen same music again and again while navigating......

Comment: Have you thought about whether the user wants any music playing *at all*? Background music is very distracting and not looked upon well at all.

Comment: What if the user doesn't want your music? Do they still have to waste their bandwidth to download a 10 min song? What if they are on a mobile and in public and have a low data cap and don't want to disturb people. If you are designing the site... *please, please, rethink autoplaying music!!!*

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr i am also giving Pause button if the user does not want listen.....

Comment: By the time they hit pause, its already started playing and already started downloading.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr assuming that 1) the music can't be stopped and 2) will be annoying in the context of an unknown website are not helpful comments. Though I do agree, nothing irritates me more then auto playing anything, let alone seemingly not-required music. Just in the context of the question and SO your comments don't help him solve the problem. Maybe he has no control over this aspect and is just required to implement it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to play music in the background across pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738802/how-to-play-music-in-the-background-across-pages)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not quite easy to accomplish.
There are two practices you may follow, with the first being the most common (IMHO).

1. Sites that have a music background that doesn't start all over when you navigate, mostly use Ajax or similar methods to navigate, instead of allowing the page to normally refresh. This is mostly common with flash websites, but it is possible to do with Ajax refreshing just the inner content of your site.
2. The second way would involve somehow passing on a variable that remembers where the user was, but you cannot avoid the loading gaps, and the whole result would be very uncommon and not really pleasant.

Comment: Having a setTimeout JS function run every second, possibly updating a cookie, to keep the last second played, and assume that you will get a close-to-good result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this off the top of my head. The easiest would probably be some JavaScript that would load the content of the next page into the current page:

```
<div id="content">[Your changing page content goes in here]</div>
```

A link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadNext('somepage.html')">Some Page</a>
```

Some JS:

```
function loadNext(page){
    //using jquery
    // assigning to a var like this lets you do things like abort the call
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({type:"get",url:page,dataType:"text"});

    jqxhr.success(function(result){ $("#content").html(result); });
}
```

Another, probably simpler way is to load your page content into an iframe and then just have them navigate within that, that'd be a lot safer too as it won't break if people have JS disabled.

```
<iframe src="homepage.html"></iframe> //You'll need to size this to whatever the content needs obviously, like 'style="width:100%;height:100%"'
```

Both of these solutions require that your content be able to be separately loaded from the wrapper of the page, so that things like headers and footers don't duplicate infinitely as you navigate around.