# Continuously playing sticky-footer music player for wordpress website for all pages

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, sticky-footer, audio-player

I bought 3 music players **(1) tPlayer - audio player (with playlist) for WP**, **(2) Sticky Shoutcast & Icecast Radio Player — «Line-R» w/ AAC+** , **(3) AIO Radio Station Player - Shoutcast, Icecast and more**) from [codecanyon.net](http://codecanyon.net/item/tplayer-audio-player-with-playlist-for-wp/12005417)

I want a sticky-footer music player fixed to the bottom of the browser window that runs even we browse inside a website which includes that  player like in [sound cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdGkd.jpg) website(not exactly) 
but with 'now playing' and a 'popup' options in it. Is there any possible way to  achieve this with the above mentioned players..or any other suggestion is appreciable..

please help me solve this..this is really important to me.

Comment: For this you need your site to be a SPA, which changes its content dynamically instead of actually reloading the page. Once you leave a page, the music will stop. It's less to do with the specific player, and all to do with the basic structure of your site. Since Wordpress by default isn't a SPA, you'll have to invest quite some work into making it one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. and I really don't about the SPA thing..can you please educate me..is that a really hard thing to do in 3 days..because I have only 3 days to complete this task..  and where we can go to achieve this with spending some buck?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: and I used the ajaxify plugin also..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to play music in the background across pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738802/how-to-play-music-in-the-background-across-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Advanced AJAX Page Loader Wordpress plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

to make your Wordpress website behave like a SPA and create a sticky player in the footer, that will not interrupt playing while you navigate your website.
I can tell you that it's 100% working solution as I have experience creating Internet-radio websites that use it.

Comment: Can you please send me the link of the player that you used in your website. Thanks.

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/sound-music-theme-with-continuous-playback/13294012

Comment: Thanks...but, does AAPL works for any of those players that I bought? Mainly for tplayer..

Comment: I have tried jPlayer & Soundmanager 2 - both working well, can't say anything about tplayer - never tried it.

Comment: Can you please tell me that using these players in my website difficult process or any coder can do this one day? (I am proficient in html, css and javascript)...or is there any documentation that shows how to stick the jplayer or Soundmanager to the footer of the word press website? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it'easy enough. You have to make a DIV with a fixed position at the bottom for your player, then create a main DIV with the page content that will be reloaded with AAPL. If you look at the Sound theme above - you will notice that it work just that way - player in a separate DIV at the bottom.

Comment: Can you do this job for me...I ll send you the details. Because its really important to me. If you do this job for me..then you are a life saver..if you agree then we can talk about further details..thanks

Comment: And all of the code is word press php.. I don't know how to edit them

Comment: I'm available for hire at Upwork https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/users/_~01e3b1c1e09e175f67/